# how to install python2 packages via pip when I have both python2 and python3?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

Now

> pip -V

shows that it's python3.5's pip.

What to do if I want python2's package?

Comment: `pip2 install <pkg-name>`

Comment: python2.7 -m pip install <package>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$pip2 install [package name]` as it says in the comments but down the road your life will be much easier if you use virtual environments to compartmentalize your code. That way you specify which python version to use in your project only once (at the beginning) and then you can configure pip to always install packages for that version.